# window.open if success in jQuery function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function

This code is on my footer.php file and I included it in the page. What I want is to run this code in my check address jQuery if the data is equal to passed. I also tried putting this code in the same page and still not working.

```
<script src="//www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js" async></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.paypalCheckoutReady = function () {
      paypal.checkout.setup('<?php echo($merchantID); ?>', {
          button: 'placeOrderBtn',
          environment: '<?php echo($env); ?>',
          condition: function () {
                  return document.getElementById('paypal_payment_option').checked === true;
              }
      });
  };
</script>
```

This is were I want to insert the paypalCheckoutReady function if(data == 'passed); then run the function and open a window.

```
 <script>
   function check_address(){
    var data = {
        'first_name' : jQuery('#first_name').val(),
        'last_name' : jQuery('#last_name').val(),
        'street' : jQuery('#street').val(),
        'street2' : jQuery('#street2').val(),
        'city' : jQuery('#city').val(),
        'state' : jQuery('#state').val(),
        'zip_code' : jQuery('#zip_code').val(),
        'country' : jQuery('#country').val(),
        'phone' : jQuery('#phone').val(),
        'notetext' : jQuery('#notetext').val(),
    };
    jQuery.ajax({
        url : '/proj/admin/parsers/check_address.php',
        method : 'POST',
        data : data,
        success : function(data){
            if(data != 'passed'){
                jQuery('#payment-errors').html(data);
            }
            if(data == 'passed'){
                jQuery('#payment-errors').html("");

            /*I want to run the window.open code here*/
                paypalCheckoutReady(); //I tried this but not working
            }
        },
        error : function(){alert("Something Went Wrong");},
    });
} 
  </script>

<?php
 } else {

 $resArray = CallShortcutExpressCheckout ($_POST, $returnURL, $cancelURL);
 $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);
 if($ack=="SUCCESS" || $ack=="SUCCESSWITHWARNING")  //if SetExpressCheckout API call is successful
 {
    RedirectToPayPal ( $resArray["TOKEN"] );
 } 
 else  
 {
 //Display a user friendly Error on the page using any of the following error information returned by PayPal
 $ErrorCode = urldecode($resArray["L_ERRORCODE0"]);
 $ErrorShortMsg = urldecode($resArray["L_SHORTMESSAGE0"]);
 $ErrorLongMsg = urldecode($resArray["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]);
 $ErrorSeverityCode = urldecode($resArray["L_SEVERITYCODE0"]);

 echo "SetExpressCheckout API call failed. ";
 echo "Detailed Error Message: " . $ErrorLongMsg;
 echo "Short Error Message: " . $ErrorShortMsg;
 echo "Error Code: " . $ErrorCode;
 echo "Error Severity Code: " . $ErrorSeverityCode;
 }
}
?>
<?php include 'includes/footer.php'; ?>
```

Hope you can help me with this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may have a race condition.

Try moving

```
<script src="//www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js" async></script>
```

after your script.

If PayPal's .js file is cached locally it may initialize before your code runs, and then the `paypalCheckoutReady` function won't ever get called.

Answer (score -1):

As in you want the function to run? Then just invoke it there.

```
...
if (data == 'passed') {
  jQuery('#payment-errors').html("")
  paypalCheckoutReady(); // you don't need to type window.
}
...
```

Comment: @EricChoi What's not working? Are there any errors? Do you have jQuery included on the page?

Comment: yes i included it in the file, no errors but not working. window does not open. ill edit my post and paste all the code

Comment: I edited my post and hope you can understand my problem more. sorry for my bad english not my native language.

Comment: no no no - this method is called by PayPal's Javascript itself to indicate it is complete and ready. you MUST NOT call it yourself!